# CakePHP - findAll() ordering of hasMany model

Tags: cakephp

Here are my models:

```
class Subject extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('SubjectGroup');
}

class SubjectGroup extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Subjects');
}
```

I am retrieving all SubjectGroups in my controller like this:

```
$this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array('order' => 'SubjectGroup.name'));
```

But how do I also tell it to order the Subjects within each SubjectGroup by Subject.name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

```
class SubjectGroup extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Subject' => array('order' => 'Subject.name')
    );

}
```

Thanks to chetan patel for reminding me of the advanced options.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->SubjectGroup->find('all', array('order' => array('SubjectGroup.name'=>'asc','Subject.name'=>'asc')));
```

or

```
class SubjectGroup extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
   'Subject'=>array(
   'className' => 'Subject',
  'order' => 'Subject.name DESC', // order by descending time of Subjects
  'foreignKey' => 'subject_id')
    );
 }
```

Comment: Nope.  Already tried that.

**SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Subject.name' in 'order clause'**

Comment: Thanks.  The second solution is the right idea (I remember reading it in the manual when I first learnt Cake), but your syntax is wrong.  Please note that the first solution is incorrect.  All that does is attempts to sort the parent model (SubjectGroup) by a first and then second column.  Unfortunately, it won't have a column called `Subject.name`.